# Flash update.img using flash_image

Tags: updates, rom-flashing, shell

I want to flash a new ROM using the shell. (Need this later to do per app so there is no other way than shell). Here is what I tried

```
connected to 192.168.1.9:5555
Pauls-MacBook-Pro:~$ adb shell
root@android:/ # su
root@android:/ # flash_image
usage: flash_image partition file.img
root@android:/ # flash_image boot /mnt/sdcard/_updateboot.img
error opening /mnt/sdcard/_updateboot.img: No such file or directory
1|root@android:/ # flash_image boot /mnt/sdcard/_update/boot.img               
root@android:/ # flash_image misc /mnt/sdcard/_update/misc.img                 
root@android:/ # flash_image kernel /mnt/sdcard/_update/kernel.img             
root@android:/ # flash_image recovery /mnt/sdcard/_update/recovery.img         
root@android:/ # flash_image system /mnt/sdcard/_update/system.img             
mtd: write error (No space left on device)
error writing system: No space left on device
1|root@android:/ # flash_image system /mnt/sdcard/_update/system.img           
mtd: write error (No space left on device)
error writing system: No space left on device
1|root@android:/ # reboot
```

Even if I don't get the No space error it just wouldn't boot (it is a TV dongle, so no HDMI output). Has anyone an idea how to flash ROMs from an ROM?

Comment: To avoid the "no space left" problem, you could re-pack your image file as described in [Removing files from & repackaging CyanogenMod ROM zip files](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33932/removing-files-from-repackaging-cyanogenmod-rom-zip-files/33934#33934). Though that might not solve your final issue ("not booting"), it should at least help a bit.

Comment: These aren't zips. There are only .img like boot, kernel, recovery, system ... But I will try to modify them maybe it will work.

Comment: Might be Yaffs images, in which case you might want to look out for the [yaffs2utils](http://code.google.com/p/yaffs2utils/) or [yaffs_tools](http://code.google.com/p/1073-max/downloads/detail?name=yaffs_tools.zip&can=2&q=) to handle them.